# Relations between lists in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to build a simple CRM like solution inside SharePoint 2010 with three lists.
The first list stores companies and the second stores contact persons on these companies with a lookup column where you select the company the person works at.
The third list (and this is where the problem comes) stores communication with the people at the companies so here I have a lookup column that looks up people that are in list number 2.

The problem is that I want to group the third list on company and then on person in the view but I can't group on a column not in the third list and SharePoint won't let me have a column containing the company name in the third list since it is a lookup column in the second list.

Anybody have a clue if this can be done with SharePoint lists and views?

Answer (score 0):

you can still make a column in the third list though it wont be containing the same info as the company column in the second list. This relationship can be done in SharePoint, it just cant be shown in a view configurated in the UI.

What you need to do is either create a webpart in which you show the information you need by creating a grid or use a custom solution to create a new fieldtype like they did with the "filtered lookup field" on

[filtered lookup on codeplex](http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Filtered LookUps Column](http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/) as avaliable in codeplex solution.. When you create a column with Filtered lookup , it will provide you an option to create new column using a column defined in another list or You can even generate a query on that list or you can create view for the same.